# Difference between std::set and boost::container::set

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

What is the main difference between **std::set** and **boost::container::set** ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main difference between boost containers and standard containers is that boost containers allow for incomplete types. This can make a huge difference when implementing more complex data structures that rely on a combination of underlying containers.

There might be performance differences between boost containers and particular implementations of standard containers. But that could go either way.

**EDIT**: Here are some additional notes for set/map containers (see [ref](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/main_features.html)):

[multi]set/map containers are size optimized embedding the color bit of the red-black tree nodes in the parent pointer.
[multi]set/map containers use no recursive functions so stack problems are avoided.

Comment: also, boost containers vouch not to allocate on default construction, IIRC

Comment: @sehe Yup that appears to be true too. That's probably more meaningful for the vector-like containers.

Comment: You might had another difference: the implementation of boost containers are globally the same whatever the compiler/platform you use, while the standard library version will often be implemented with specific optimizations. It's not good nor bad, it just depends on what you actually need.

Comment: Another difference is that some proposals for future inclusion in the standard library (like the find() function in set and map which could take any type instead of the key type, as long as they can be used to search) are often inplemented in boost before standardization, which can help in some cases.

Comment: @Klaim I think these are valid points, but these are generally true of most Boost libraries, it's not specific to boost containers per se.

Comment: @MikaelPersson Yes but only these libraries implementing the standard library, which is still a minority of boost libraries.