# What is the difference between boost::container::vector and std::vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector

What is the difference between [boost::container::vector](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost/container/vector.html) and [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)?

Comment: I found a related question that probably answers this one as well:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584685/difference-between-stdset-and-boostcontainerset

Comment: IIRC, Boost.Container is compatible with Boost.Move, meaning its containers support move semantics without C++11.

Comment: @jfritz42 agreed, where my comment is extra relevant for you since you're using a vector

Answer (score 14):

A case where you may need the boost version instead of the standard version is when you encounter the `<bool>` specialization.

`std::vector<bool>` is implemented as a bitset, it doesn't store its element as an array of `bool`.

This means for instance the following code will not work:

```
template<T>
void handleElement(T &element);

// suppose we get a bool vector:
std::vector<bool> v = ....;
// then this fails because v[i] is a proxy object
handleElement(v[0]);
```

`boost::container::vector<bool>` has no such specialization.

Answer (score 5):

There are several differences that I could compile:

° No specialization of `boost::container::vector<bool>` (source @roeland)

```
decltype(std::vector<bool>(10)[0]) == std::_Bit_reference
decltype(boost::container::vector<bool>(10)[0]) == bool&
```

° Uses Boost allocator infrastructure, which (especially in C++1x) is more flexible that the standard allocator, doesn't ignore certain traits that are provided by the allocator. (source: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.stl_container_requirements)

```
std::vector<double>::allocator_type == std::allocator<double>
boost::container::vector<double>::alloctor_type == boost::container::new_allocator<double>
```

In particular, one can still specify the `reference` and `pointer` types to be different from `T&` and `T*` (see [Is it still possible to customize STL vector's "reference" type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41580521/is-it-still-possible-to-customize-stl-vectors-reference-type/41581304#41581304))

° Support for recursive containers (source: The Boost C++ Libraries by Boris Schäling).

Some (old?) implementations of STL didn't support incomplete value types (they were not required in the first place), in particular recursive containers.

```
using boost::container::vector;

struct animal{
    vector<animal> children; // may not work with std::vector
};

int main(){
    animal parent;
    animal child1;
    animal child2;

    parent.children.push_back(child1);
    parent.children.push_back(child2);
}
```

° `std::vector` is a specification not an implementation.
There is only one implementation `boost::container::vector` across all platforms, so more assumptions can be made (for example originally `std::vector` was not required to use contiguous memory) (source: The Boost C++ Libraries by Boris Schäling).