# Is it still possible to customize STL vector's "reference" type?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, stl, allocator

Is it possible to customize the `reference` of a `std::vector`. 
Until C++11 it seemed to be possible through the `Allocator` template parameter.
But not anymore?

According to the documentation, http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector,  `reference` is now always `value_type` and `value_type` is always the template parameter `T`.

It seems to be impossible even using `allocator_traits`,
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits

Is there a workaround for this?

If not, does it means that I have to specialize the entire `std::vector` and probably reproduce all its functionality if I want to have a special `reference` type based on the allocator?

If this is so, generally speaking what is the logic for all these constrains? To force the user to use `std::vector<T, A>` to always manage regular memory (in which, `value_type = T`, `reference = T&` and `pointer = T*`?)

---

Note: I am aware of the `std::vector<bool>` controversy. However this a bit more general because in principle I need a custom `std::vector<RegularType, special_allocator<RegularType>>` mainly to control the return type of `operator[](int)` to a special proxy object.

---

Specific implementation: I am looking at GCC 6.3.1's stdlib source and in `std_vector.h` one can read:

```
template<typename _Tp, ...>
class vector : ...{
   ...
   public:
   typedef typename _Alloc_traits::reference          reference;
};
```

which seems to indicate that it is still possible to specify a reference type via the `allocator` (`_traits`?).

According to the documentation, `allocator` or the `allocator_traits` doesn't need to have a `reference` type.
Plus, I don't know how to customize this type anyway.

Is GCC not following the standard? Or is it simply that indirectly `allocator_traits<Allocator>::reference` is forced to be `allocator_traits<Allocator>::value_type&`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If this is so, generally speaking what is the logic for all these constrains?

The purpose is to stop promising things C++ cannot deliver.

Back in the C++98/03 days, it was thought that proxy types, specialized references and the like could really work with standard library containers and algorithms. By the time C++11 rolled around, it had become abundantly clear that... no, they really can't. Or at least, not with the same semantics as an actual language reference.

With that wisdom in mind, C++11 removed a lot of these no-longer-reasonable customization points. The typedefs were left in, but mainly for backwards-compatibility's sake.

> which seems to indicate that it is still possible to specify a reference type via the allocator (_traits?).

No, it isn't. This is a bug in libstdc++; `reference` is *required* to be `value_type&` for containers now. `allocator_traits` has no `reference` customization point.

Comment: Thank you for the very straight forward response. Maybe once we have smart references (overload dot) they can put back these customization points. Do you have a recommendation for a workaround? or at least a mindset?, after all, if one now wants something that has the internal logic of a `std::vector`, it seems that one has to roll out a complete reimplementation of the class.

Comment: On the "bug" in gcc: Actually, it looks like gcc has a "parallel" `allocator_traits` called `__gnu_cxx::__allocator_traits` that is disconnected from `std::allocator_traits`, and it is used in `std::vector`. So `std::allocator_traits::< >::reference`, it is still not a customization points. (I think the standard went overboard with removing customization points, I customized `__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<myalloc>` for fun and it seems to work.)

Comment: Perhaps an option is to customize `boost::container::vector<T, Alloc>` instead. It seems to still have many customization points that `std::vector`/`std::allocator_traits` lost.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html#interprocess.allocators_containers.containers_explained.stl_container_requirements

Comment: I looked into this problem again, `std::vector` now (C++11) is so constrained that a `std::vector<T>::iterator` might as well be a `T*` and be done with it.

Comment: I gave a shot to Boost Container vector, and failed miserably because of a very small detail, `resize`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958308/can-boost-container-vector-manage-memory-through-non-raw-pointers