# What is the difference between std::unordered_map and boost::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, unordered-map

I found both container used in our codes. This is a bit of confusing, especially when I include libs that depends on both of them. 
So what is the main difference between these two implementations? Are they interchangeable in all cases? Or which should I prefer when I choose from them?

Comment: almost everything in `std` is proposed first in `boost`. then it is made part of `std` library.

Comment: @user1: Not even close to everything, or almost everything, but it is the case for `unordered_map`.

Comment: `boost::unordered_` documents the variations from the C++11 Standard [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/unordered/compliance.html), which you could have found in the 9th sentence of the Introduction [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/unordered.html).

Comment: Reopened (the `boost::containers` library does *not* contain `boost::unordered_map`, nor any hashtable based container, so this is not a duplicate of Łukasz Kosiak's question about `set` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584685/difference-between-stdset-and-boostcontainerset?lq=1)).

Answer (score 0):

unlike std counterpart boost::unordered_map (and probably other containers) allows using of incomplete types. that difference probably might change though, see for example https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/sykzng/since_when_does_gcc_support_stdunordered_map_with/